# Android Apps and Root Access

Tags: android, api

From browsing StackOverflow I understand how an app gets root privileges (the "su" command) but does the app need root access to do the following commands?

1. Turn Bluetooth On/Off
2. Turn WiFi On/Off
3. Turn Mobile Data On/Off

The reason I ask is that for a unit of my studies, I am wanting to create a basic AI using either text input or the google api for speech recognition. I would like it to be able to control phone functions to make a true "assistant in your pocket". Code samples will be useful but a simple text explanation will be more than sufficient.

I apologize if this has been asked before but searching didn't find my question.

Many Thanks in Advance,
James

Comment: Google is your friend. Just search for "android disable xxxx programmatically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need root for those operations, you just need to have the [permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for those actions in the application manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />`